# S3AFileSystem - S3 Access Key and Secret Key

Tags: java, amazon-s3, hadoop, databricks

I am trying to read/write the S3 bucket and develop code in JAVA. While I am running the code I am getting authorization error for Access key and Secret key.

I have defined fs as follows:

```
Configuration conf = new Configuration()
S3AFileSystem fs = (S3AFileSystem) FileSystem.get(conf)
FSDataOutputStream ostm = fs.open(new Path(s3bucketpath))
```

while it is creating fs, it is throwing an error :

```
shaded.databricks.org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem cannot be cast to org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem
java.lang.ClassCastException: shaded.databricks.org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem cannot be cast to org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem
```

Looks like it is looking for access key and secret key while creating fs and could someone guide me how we can pass them to FileSystem(conf).

Please provide sample code if you can guide me to implement this.

Thanks

Comment: A cast exception has nothing to do with access keys. You need to change your imports to use the shaded databricks s3a filesystem. And you don't pass the keys through the config, you export them in environment variables before running the code

Comment: thank you for your response. Can you guide me on which maven package we need to add to have databricks s3a filesystem?

Comment: Which dependency do you have already? Are you referring to DBFS?

Comment: I have org.apache.hadoop.fs._ . As you mentioned  "imports to use the shaded databricks s3a filesystem", what library I need to add?

Comment: According to your error, you dont need to add anything; you already have it. I was saying replace `import org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem` line with `import shaded.databricks.org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem`